# Read in paragraph as one list element

Tags: python, string, list, file

I have a text file filled with thousands of item reviews like this:

```
+1  This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1.  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]
+1  I bought this a few times for my older son and have bought it again for my newborn. This is super easy to use and helps me keep track of his daily routine. When he started going to the sitter when I went back to work, it helped me know how his day went to better prepare me for how the evening would most likely go. When he was sick, it help me keep track of how many diapers a day he was producing to make sure he was getting dehydrated. The note sections to the side and bottom are useful too because his sitter writes in small notes about whether or not he liked his lunch or if the playtime included going for a walk, etc.Excellent for moms who are wanting to keep track of their kids daily routine even though they are at work. Excellent for dads to keep track as my husband can quickly forget what time he fed our son. LOL
+1  This is great for basics, but I wish the space to write things in was bigger. A lot times I need struggle trying to read what the caretaker wrote in because the spaces go together.
+1  This book is perfect!  I'm a first time new mom, and this book made it so easy to keep track of feedings, diaper changes, sleep.  Definitely would recommend this for new moms.  Plus it's small enough that I throw in the diaper back for doctor visits.
```

Each review is separated by a new line and the review sentiment is separated from the review by a tab.

This is my code that correctly puts each sentiment and review in their respective arrays:

```
# read in training data, 18506 reviews
trainingFile = open(r"D:\Desktop\\1565964985_2925534_train_file.data", "r")

# arrays for the sentiments and reviews
sentiment = []
review = []

# for loop that reads each line
for line in trainingFile:
    # data field array separated by tab
    dataFields = line.split("\t")

    # sentiment holds the positive or negative sentiment of the review
    sentiment.append(dataFields[0])
    # review holds the text from the review
    review.append(dataFields[1])

# test print statement
for x in range(len(sentiment)):
    print(sentiment[x])

for x in range(len(review)):
    print(review[x])
```

Here lies the issue: I'm doing Bag of Words on these review paragraphs and the current code

```
print(review[0])
print(type(review[0]))
count = CountVectorizer()
docs = numpy.array(review[0])
bag = count.fit_transform(docs)
print(bag.toarray())
```

Error:

```
TypeError: iteration over a 0-d array
```

So I tried reading in the reviews differently:

```
review.append(dataFields[1].split())
```

Now this is my result:

```
['This', 'book', 'is', 'such', 'a', 'life', 'saver.', 'It', 'has', 'been', 'so', 'helpful', 'to', 'be', 'able', 'to', 'go', 'back', 'to', 'track', 'trends,', 'answer', 'pediatrician', 'questions,', 'or', 'communicate', 'with', 'each', 'other', 'when', 'you', 'are', 'up', 'at', 'different', 'times', 'of', 'the', 'night', 'with', 'a', 'newborn.', 'I', 'think', 'it', 'is', 'one', 'of', 'those', 'things', 'that', 'everyone', 'should', 'be', 'required', 'to', 'have', 'before', 'they', 'leave', 'the', 'hospital.', 'We', 'went', 'through', 'all', 'the', 'pages', 'of', 'the', 'newborn', 'version,', 'then', 'moved', 'to', 'the', 'infant', 'version,', 'and', 'will', 'finish', 'up', 'the', 'second', 'infant', 'book', '(third', 'total)', 'right', 'as', 'our', 'baby', 'turns', '1.', 'See', 'other', 'things', 'that', 'are', 'must', 'haves', 'for', 'baby', 'at', '[...]']
<class 'list'>
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

This is what I desire:

```
review[0] = ["This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer"
             " pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night"
             " with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they"
             " leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant"
             " version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1."
             "  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]"]
print(type(review[0]))
count = CountVectorizer()
docs = numpy.array(review[0])
bag = count.fit_transform(docs)
print(count.get_feature_names())
print(bag.toarray())
```

output:

```
<class 'list'>
['able', 'all', 'and', 'answer', 'are', 'as', 'at', 'baby', 'back', 'be', 'been', 'before', 'book', 'communicate', 'different', 'each', 'everyone', 'finish', 'for', 'go', 'has', 'have', 'haves', 'helpful', 'hospital', 'infant', 'is', 'it', 'leave', 'life', 'moved', 'must', 'newborn', 'night', 'of', 'one', 'or', 'other', 'our', 'pages', 'pediatrician', 'questions', 'required', 'right', 'saver', 'second', 'see', 'should', 'so', 'such', 'that', 'the', 'then', 'they', 'things', 'think', 'third', 'this', 'those', 'through', 'times', 'to', 'total', 'track', 'trends', 'turns', 'up', 'version', 'we', 'went', 'when', 'will', 'with', 'you']
[[1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 3 1
  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 6 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1
  2 1]]
```

So my big question is how do I read in my text to my desired format?

```
Full code + outputs:

import re
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import numpy
import math

# def euclideanDistance


# read in training data, 18506 reviews
trainingFile = open(r"D:\Desktop\\1565964985_2925534_train_file.data", "r")

# arrays for the sentiments and reviews
sentiment = []
review = []

# for loop that reads each line
for line in trainingFile:
    # data field array separated by tab
    dataFields = line.split("\t")

    # sentiment holds the positive or negative sentiment of the review
    sentiment.append(dataFields[0])
    # review holds the text from the review
    review.append(dataFields[1].split())

# test print statement
#for x in range(len(sentiment)):
   # print(sentiment[x])

#for x in range(len(review)):
   # print(review[x])

print(review[0])
print(type(review[0]))
count = CountVectorizer()
docs = numpy.array(review[0])
bag = count.fit_transform(docs)
print(bag.toarray())
print("\n\n\n")

review[0] = ["This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer"
             " pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night"
             " with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they"
             " leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant"
             " version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1."
             "  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]"]
print(type(review[0]))
count = CountVectorizer()
docs = numpy.array(review[0])
bag = count.fit_transform(docs)
print(count.get_feature_names())
print(bag.toarray())

trainingFile.close()

['This', 'book', 'is', 'such', 'a', 'life', 'saver.', 'It', 'has', 'been', 'so', 'helpful', 'to', 'be', 'able', 'to', 'go', 'back', 'to', 'track', 'trends,', 'answer', 'pediatrician', 'questions,', 'or', 'communicate', 'with', 'each', 'other', 'when', 'you', 'are', 'up', 'at', 'different', 'times', 'of', 'the', 'night', 'with', 'a', 'newborn.', 'I', 'think', 'it', 'is', 'one', 'of', 'those', 'things', 'that', 'everyone', 'should', 'be', 'required', 'to', 'have', 'before', 'they', 'leave', 'the', 'hospital.', 'We', 'went', 'through', 'all', 'the', 'pages', 'of', 'the', 'newborn', 'version,', 'then', 'moved', 'to', 'the', 'infant', 'version,', 'and', 'will', 'finish', 'up', 'the', 'second', 'infant', 'book', '(third', 'total)', 'right', 'as', 'our', 'baby', 'turns', '1.', 'See', 'other', 'things', 'that', 'are', 'must', 'haves', 'for', 'baby', 'at', '[...]']
<class 'list'>
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]




<class 'list'>
['able', 'all', 'and', 'answer', 'are', 'as', 'at', 'baby', 'back', 'be', 'been', 'before', 'book', 'communicate', 'different', 'each', 'everyone', 'finish', 'for', 'go', 'has', 'have', 'haves', 'helpful', 'hospital', 'infant', 'is', 'it', 'leave', 'life', 'moved', 'must', 'newborn', 'night', 'of', 'one', 'or', 'other', 'our', 'pages', 'pediatrician', 'questions', 'required', 'right', 'saver', 'second', 'see', 'should', 'so', 'such', 'that', 'the', 'then', 'they', 'things', 'think', 'third', 'this', 'those', 'through', 'times', 'to', 'total', 'track', 'trends', 'turns', 'up', 'version', 'we', 'went', 'when', 'will', 'with', 'you']
[[1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 3 1
  1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 6 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 5 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1
  2 1]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to have your sentiments as `[+1, 0, -1]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your sentiment values could be one of `[+1, 0, -1]`, the following code should do the trick.

## Data

I modified your sample data to ensure all types of sentiment values are present in it.

```py
data_string = """
-1  This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1.  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]
+1  I bought this a few times for my older son and have bought it again for my newborn. This is super easy to use and helps me keep track of his daily routine. When he started going to the sitter when I went back to work, it helped me know how his day went to better prepare me for how the evening would most likely go. When he was sick, it help me keep track of how many diapers a day he was producing to make sure he was getting dehydrated. The note sections to the side and bottom are useful too because his sitter writes in small notes about whether or not he liked his lunch or if the playtime included going for a walk, etc.Excellent for moms who are wanting to keep track of their kids daily routine even though they are at work. Excellent for dads to keep track as my husband can quickly forget what time he fed our son. LOL
0  This is great for basics, but I wish the space to write things in was bigger. A lot times I need struggle trying to read what the caretaker wrote in because the spaces go together.
+1  This book is perfect!  I'm a first time new mom, and this book made it so easy to keep track of feedings, diaper changes, sleep.  Definitely would recommend this for new moms.  Plus it's small enough that I throw in the diaper back for doctor visits.
"""

# convert to a list of lines (strings)
data_lines = [line.strip() for line in data_string.split('\n') if line.strip()!='']
# print data_lines
data_lines
```

You could do this to read the data as a list of lines from the file.

```py
with open("filename.csv", "r") as f:
    data_lines = f.readlines()
```

#### Output:

```
['-1  This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1.  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]',
 '+1  I bought this a few times for my older son and have bought it again for my newborn. This is super easy to use and helps me keep track of his daily routine. When he started going to the sitter when I went back to work, it helped me know how his day went to better prepare me for how the evening would most likely go. When he was sick, it help me keep track of how many diapers a day he was producing to make sure he was getting dehydrated. The note sections to the side and bottom are useful too because his sitter writes in small notes about whether or not he liked his lunch or if the playtime included going for a walk, etc.Excellent for moms who are wanting to keep track of their kids daily routine even though they are at work. Excellent for dads to keep track as my husband can quickly forget what time he fed our son. LOL',
 '0  This is great for basics, but I wish the space to write things in was bigger. A lot times I need struggle trying to read what the caretaker wrote in because the spaces go together.',
 "+1  This book is perfect!  I'm a first time new mom, and this book made it so easy to keep track of feedings, diaper changes, sleep.  Definitely would recommend this for new moms.  Plus it's small enough that I throw in the diaper back for doctor visits."]
```

## Solution:

```py
sentiments = list()
reviews = list()
for i, line in enumerate(data_lines):
    s = ''.join(re.findall("^[+1]*[-1]*[0]*", line))
    r = line.replace(s,'').strip()
    print('line:{} \n\t sentiment: {} \n\t review: {}'.format(i, s, r))
    sentiments.append(s)
    reviews.append(r)
```

#### Output

```
line:0 
     sentiment: -1 
     review: This book is such a life saver.  It has been so helpful to be able to go back to track trends, answer pediatrician questions, or communicate with each other when you are up at different times of the night with a newborn.  I think it is one of those things that everyone should be required to have before they leave the hospital.  We went through all the pages of the newborn version, then moved to the infant version, and will finish up the second infant book (third total) right as our baby turns 1.  See other things that are must haves for baby at [...]
line:1 
     sentiment: +1 
     review: I bought this a few times for my older son and have bought it again for my newborn. This is super easy to use and helps me keep track of his daily routine. When he started going to the sitter when I went back to work, it helped me know how his day went to better prepare me for how the evening would most likely go. When he was sick, it help me keep track of how many diapers a day he was producing to make sure he was getting dehydrated. The note sections to the side and bottom are useful too because his sitter writes in small notes about whether or not he liked his lunch or if the playtime included going for a walk, etc.Excellent for moms who are wanting to keep track of their kids daily routine even though they are at work. Excellent for dads to keep track as my husband can quickly forget what time he fed our son. LOL
line:2 
     sentiment: 0 
     review: This is great for basics, but I wish the space to write things in was bigger. A lot times I need struggle trying to read what the caretaker wrote in because the spaces go together.
line:3 
     sentiment: +1 
     review: This book is perfect!  I'm a first time new mom, and this book made it so easy to keep track of feedings, diaper changes, sleep.  Definitely would recommend this for new moms.  Plus it's small enough that I throw in the diaper back for doctor visits.
```

I hope this helps.